# react-native-maps: How to display callout within map boundaries?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

A problem that I have with the following code: only part of the callout is visible (part of it is hidden by the screen title). Is there a simple way to display all of it?

### Here is how it looks:

[image]

### And this is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Modal, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { MapView } from 'expo';

const mapCoord = {
  latitude: 35.6,
  longitude: 139.8,
  latitudeDelta: 4,
  longitudeDelta: 4
};

const city = { latitude: 37.0, longitude: 140.5 };

export default class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMapReady: false,
      appModalVisible: false
    };
  }

  onMapLayout() {
    this.setState({ isMapReady: true });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={styles.headerViewStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.headerStyle}>
            Map Title
          </Text>
        </View>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          zoomEnabled = {false}
          rotateEnabled = {false}
          scrollEnabled = {false}
          region={mapCoord}
          onLayout={this.onMapLayout.bind(this)}
          onPress={(e) => this.onMapPress(e)}
        >
        {this.state.isMapReady &&
          <View>
            <MapView.Marker
              coordinate={city}
              stopPropagation = {true}
              ref={marker => {
                this.marker1 = marker;
              }}
              onPress={() => {console.log("Marker/onPress");}}
              onCalloutPress={() => {console.log("Marker/onCalloutPress");
                this.marker1.hideCallout();}}
            >
              <MapView.Callout>
                <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                    info:
                  </Text>
                  <Text>
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </MapView.Callout>
            </MapView.Marker>
          </View>
        }
      </MapView>
        <Modal
          animationType="slide"
          transparent={false}
          visible={this.state.appModalVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {
            this.setState({ appModalVisible: false });
          }}>
          <View style={styles.modalContainerViewStyle}>
            <View style={styles.modalViewStyle}>
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
              </Text>
              <View style={{ height: 40, margin: 5 }}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonStyle}
                  onPress={() => { this.setState({ appModalVisible: false }); }}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>OK</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }

  onMapPress(e) {
    console.log("In onMapPress. coordinate: ", e.nativeEvent.coordinate);
    this.setState({ appModalVisible: true });
  }
}

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 16,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        padding: 5
      },
      button: {
        width: 80,
        paddingHorizontal: 12,
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginHorizontal: 10
      },
      buttonContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        marginVertical: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      },
      viewStyle: {
        width: 200,
        height: 250,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        padding: 20
      },
      headerViewStyle: {
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
        shadowOpacity: 0.2,
        shadowRadius: 2,
        elevation: 3,
        position: 'relative'
      },
      headerStyle: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: "bold"
      },
      modalContainerViewStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#00000080'
      },
      modalViewStyle: {
        width: 300,
        height: 380,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        padding: 20
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it adding **mapPadding** property to MapView. You have to add some top padding. That should work.

*mapPadding*    -  Adds custom padding to each side of the map. Useful when map elements/markers are obscured.

[Documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md)

Example code:

```
    <MapView
      style={{
        height: MAP_HEIGHT,
        width: MAP_WIDTH
      }}
      region={{
        latitude: MAP_LATITUDE,
        longitude: MAP_LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0025,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0121
      }}
      mapPadding={{ top: MAP_HEIGHT / 4 }}
    >
    </MapView>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple way of technique is adding **ScrollView** between text content

```
<ScrollView>
   <Text>Lorem Lipsum</Text>
</ScrollView>
```

and refer more features from [ScrollView ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

Comment: what is the issue ?